# Save Success Alert only fading once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added this code which creates a fade on the success alert when it is called. When I click save the alert fades only onlce - but the second time I click save it does not do so. The alert stays there until I close it. I want the fade to work everytime I click save.

```
      $("#successalert").show(function(){
        $(".alert").delay(4600).addClass("in").fadeOut(1000)
        });
```

Comment: what does class `.in` contain?

Comment: Click save where? Need more code - what are you actually clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to addclass(".in") again on click event, and remove it in animation:

```
$("#yourButton").on("click",function(){
    $(".alert").addClass(".in");
    $("#successalert").show(function(){
        $(".alert").delay(4600).addClass("in").fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('in');
       });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Without further code it's hard to diagnose, but you may want to try changing your code to:

```
$("#successalert").show(function(){
        $(".alert").delay(4600).addClass("in").fadeOut(1000, function(){
                $(this).removeClass('in');
        })
});
```

This will reset `.alert` to its original state before being shown by removing the applied `in` class at the end of the fade.

Comment: Thanks for your reply really appreciate it - still does the same thing - only fades once. It works again when I refresh the page and click save again tho but again only once.

Answer (score 0):

To get duplicate behavior, you must reset everything you have done. After your first `.fadeOut()`, you need code that resets what you have done. You must `.removeClass('in')`, `.hide('#successalert')`, and `.show('.alert')` at some point to reset your code to its original state.

Comment: Thanks - do you know if there are any good examples of how this is done?